# How do I change the place where my vim files are stored?

Tags: save

Right now, all my vim files that I create are stored in C:\Users\dinosauce33 (My user). How do I change it so that all of my files that I create are stored in documents?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim saves unnamed files in the current directory. If you did not change it, the current directory is the one whence Vim was started, `C:\Users\dinosauce33` in your case.

Thus, you just need is to add `cd C:\Users\dinosauce33\documents` to your `.vimrc` file to change the directory to the documents directory whenever Vim is started.

Comment: But, maybe only `:cd` if `pwd() is# expand('~')`?

Comment: Hi @D.BenKnoble, Wouldn't only `:cd` result in the home directory, `C:\Users\dinosauce33`?

Comment: I omitted the documents argument for brevity; otherwise you are correct. My point was this might bite OP in the long run when they dont want to be in documents all the time. The conditional would make it so it only happens when started from home, but even then I think that’s going to cause problems if OP ever wants to actually edit files there.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Oh, sorry, I failed to notice what you had meant. That's a valid concern, but I think that shortcoming is intrinsic to the question.